# How to set only one value of object as true and rest false (switchable category)

Tags: javascript, object, switch-statement, push, categories

I'd like to make a switchable category using span tag. 
Whenever I click on a span tag, I want to write code that changes the value of the clicked span tag to `active: true` and changes the rest of the span tags to the value `active: false`. But I don't know how.. :( I wrote the function called `toggleCategory` but using this function, only toggle is possible. so please help me coding masters.. (with vanilla JS)

**Push default key&value**

```
document.querySelector('#category').addEventListener('submit', () => {
    categories.push({
        id: uuidv4(),
        active: false 
    })
})
```

**Toggle the activated category (This is Prombelem)**

```
const toggleCategory = (id) => {
    const category = categories.find((category) => category.id === id)

    if (category) {
        category.active = !category.active
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to toggle a class all on the other spans and set the clicked one to active, you can do that by selecting all tags that you're looking with a css selector and assign a click event and then insert your logic like below...

```
document.querySelectorAll('span').addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.querySelectorAll('span').forEach( (e) => { //Gets all spans on page and loop throught them removing the active class.
        e.classList.remove('active');
    });
    this.classList.add('active'); //Get clicked span (That toggled the event) and adds the active class.
});
```